# Determine the length of the filtered signal w[n], and explain how its length is related to the length of x[n] and the length of the FIR filter

Tags: matlab, signals

Determine the length of the filtered signal w[n], and
explain how its length is related to the length of x[n] and the length of the FIR filter.
How do we determine the length of the filtered signal?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFDIN.png)

Comment: http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a signal through a filter is mathematically the same as convolving them with each other.

The length of a discrete convolution = len(w) + len(x) - 1;